# Mcrypt issue in php 7.2 or greater

Tags: php, symfony, mcrypt

I am getting issue related to the M CRYPT while i updated my PHP version. I installed M CRYPT extension but its working in Ubuntu server and not working in window system,

Comment: From the manual, "*This feature was DEPRECATED in PHP 7.1.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.2.0.*". https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mcrypt.php -- there's also recommended replacements.

Answer (score 0):

```
composer require phpseclib/mcrypt_compat
```

Installed this using composer and now its working fine.

Comment: mcrypt is now deprecated.  If you can, use a more modern crypto library.